# Nested array for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm stuck trying to figure out how to loop trough nested arrays.

I have an array called worldShapes that contains child arrays. I want to loop trough the parent array and get all the child arrays from it.

Here's my attempt:

```
//Nested array

worldShapes = [

[33,108,66,141,99,174,99,207,132,207,165,207,165,240],

[132,306,165,306,165,339,165,372,132,405,99,405,99,438,132,438,165,438],

[198,339,231,339,264,372,297,372,330,405,363,438,396,438],

[198,174,198,273,231,306,264,306],

[231,174,231,240,264,273,297,273],

[396,306,462,306,495,339,495,372,528,405,528,438,561,438,594,471],

[660,504,561,504,495,504]

];

//trying to loop trough each item in the child array

(function(){
    var wShapes = worldShapes; //create a local variable
    var wLen = wShapes.length; //store the length as a variable

        for (var i = 0; i < wLen; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < wShapes[i].length; j++){
            console.log(wShapes[i][j]); //this is propably wrong, trying to access the current child item of the current parent array 
            }
        }
    })
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: What's wrong with your code? Did you tried to run it?

Comment: You've wrapped it in a function, but you don't execute the function. But why wrap it in a function at all?

Comment: Are you getting an error message with that code?

Comment: Your code looks absolutely correct. What is it not doing that you think it should be?

Comment: Note: I spontaneously added `()` after the function to make it immediately invoking.

Comment: Console is not logging anything. Shouldn't my anonymous function self-execute? I tried to wrap inside the function to keep variables local, but maybe I don't understand anonymous self-executing functions properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add `();` to the very end of your code ;-)

You've simply forgotten to invoke your anonymous function

Answer (score 3):

To execute the function, add `()`

```
(function () {
    var wShapes = worldShapes; //create a local variable
    var wLen = wShapes.length; //store the length as a variable

    for (var i = 0; i < wLen; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < wShapes[i].length; j++) {
            console.log(wShapes[i][j]); //this is propably wrong, trying to access the current child item of the current parent array 
        }
    }
}()); // here
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m92T3/)